# Access 2007 VBA Listbox lag after changing DB data or Requery

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

Ive been having an extremely annoying problem that recently started to happen.

My Listbox are not updating right away. For example on my main form "A" has a listbox with an sql statement (Simple... returns 5-20 rows). I have an edit button underneath that when clicked opens a new form to change the data. That form submits an update query and then calls a global function which requiries all of the related listboxes (the one on Form A). The only problem is the listbox doesnt change and seems to hang/lag. if i select the listbox and continuously hit f5, after a few seconds it will randomly refresh correctly.

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem is?

Ive been troubleshooting this for two days now and know its not a network problem as it also happens locally, using a recordset and looping it to manually set the listbox values works fast, but for some reason all my listboxes in my application is doing this.

Is it a setting I accidentally changed or if you define to many relationships does this happen (I recently added another table)?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, the DB is on a shared drive and is only 2MB, only recently has it started to do this.

Comment: Queries that only return 5-20 rows that can take a **long** time to return depending on the queried data.  Execution speed is not proportional to the number of rows returned.  Have you followed in debug?  Can you see the hang-up?

Comment: I have followed in debug, the code runs great, no errors are returned, the listbox just doesn't update until a few seconds later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the problem, hopefully this helps someone in the future.

It had to do with using:

```
CurrentDB.Execute
```

this method runs synchronous in the background, therefore the listbox was being refreshed before the sql UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE was complete.

To fix this I instead used:

```
Docmd.RunSQL
```

This has solved the problem, however I noticed this method only works on Microsoft Access Databases.